# C# WPF clr-namespace autocompletes but then gives error

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, xml-namespaces

So I have reverenced a class with a custom Listbox
See at the bottom of the picture...
[image 1](https://i.gyazo.com/7d84231833eb3f0f0b71ae9cb6552e85.png)
[image]
I have referenced this class with `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DynamicPorts"`

When I go to use the object in my XAML it offers my class in the autocomplete 
(so it knows it is there!!!)
but as soon as it ive typed it i get an error and my project wont build...

[image 2](https://i.gyazo.com/b1790f21e581a6f20754110c0f69d7ee.png)

[image]

What am I doing wrong??

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: I am wondering how did it allow you to have same name for a namespace and class!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your project is referencing same version of the framework as well as same profile as your referenced DLL (DynamicPorts.dll). If your project is using "4.0 Client Profile" and the referenced assembly is using full "4.0" and has dependency on full 4.0, then your project won't be able to access the reference at run/build time.

Please [see MSDN on this targeting error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668079(v=vs.100).aspx) under the section "You Have Referenced an Assembly That Is Not Included in the Client Profile"

Comment: Thanks mate.

Seems to have worked.
I also had to make sure the assembly was in the root project of the solution which seems to be the case for any references assemblies